# Correct storage of container size on 32, 64 bit

Tags: c++, 64-bit, std

I am currently converting an application to 64 bit.
I have some occurrences of the following pattern:

```
class SomeOtherClass;

class SomeClass
{
    std::vector<SomeOtherClass*> mListOfThings;

    void SomeMemberFunction (void)
    {
        // Needs to know the size of the member list variable
        unsigned int listSize = mListOfThings.size();

        // use listSize in further computations
        //...
    }
}
```

Obviously in a practical case I will not have more then MAX_INT items in my list. But I wondered if there is consensus about the 'best' way to represent this type.

Each collection defines its own return type for size(), so my first approximation would be:

```
std::vector<SomeOtherClass*>::size_type listSize = mListOfThings.size()
```

I would assume this to be correct, but (personally) I dont find this 'easy reading', so -1 for clarity.

For a c++011 aware compiler I could write

```
auto listSize = mListOfThings.size()
```

which is clearly more readable.

So my question, is the latter indeed the best way to handle storing container sizes in a variable and using them in computations, regardless of underlying architecture (win32, win64, linux, macosx) ?

Comment: I just use `int` nearly all the time. Are you really going to have more than 2**32-1 elements in there?

Comment: isnot that job of compiler to adjust ints and other types according to configuration? (i am talking about Visual Studio)

Comment: @Simple It's more an academic question with regard to scalability and generic way of working. Maybe in two or three years, we have 1024 bit systems, and suddenly my current assumption on number of items is not valid anymore. (remember: "640K ought to be enough for anybody")

Comment: @Respect2All It depends on what you're doing.  There are lots of things where physical or other constraints intervene to ensure that you cannot possibly overflow.  In financial analysis, for example, the finest you can calculate an interest rate is daily; keeping the results for each day would all for instruments of over 5 million years, where as the maximum is around 50 years.  Or if you're capturing physical data, you know the rate of capture, and you can be sure that your machine isn't going to run more than 10 years.

Comment: @JamesKanze Obviously..But important addition.
Also sometimes due to e.g. memory constraints, you would want to limit the size of your variables. So I am not advocating to use the biggest possible counter on all occasions. Programming in C++ means being very much being context aware... However, I am also thinking about future-proofness, and not always do you know the limits of your containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly you want to use is a matter of how "purist" you want your code to be.

If you're on C++11, you can just use `auto` and be done with.

Otherwise, in extremely generic code (which is designed to work with arbitrary allocators), you can use the container's nested typedef `size_type`. That is taken verbatim from the container's allocator.

In normal use of standard library containers, you can use `std::size_t`. That is the `size_type` used by the default allocators, and is the type guaranteed to be able to store any object size.

I wouldn't recommend using `[unsigned] int`, as that will likely be smaller than necessary on 64-bit platforms (it's usually left at 32 bits, although this of course depends on compiler and settings). I've actually seen production code fail due to `unsigned int` not being enough to index a container.

Comment: This is very bad advice.  Any use of `auto` for this is obfuscation, for starters, since it hides the fact that you're possibly dealing with an unsigned type.  Which, of course, you want to avoid if you're using the value as a numeric type.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's subjective. I consider it a bad idea to use a signed integer for size, because `size_t` is unsigned and it can lead to warnings & overflow. Seeing `auto` initialised with a `.size()` is clear indication of unsignedness for me (and how is `std::size_t` better than `auto` in this regard anyway?). I subscribe to the [Almost Always Auto](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) approach, so my answers follow that style.

Comment: @JamesKanze, and Angew, I tend to agree with you both. Does that make sense? As stated earlier, no approach is universally applicable. You always need to know what you're doing. 
This signed/unsigned thingie is a headache chapter in my book.

Comment: @Angew It's not that subjective.  Unsigned types should be avoided for arithmetic values or numeric values that you might want to compare, since it can lead to surprising results.  (In some ways, unsigned in C++ is broken.)  As for the "Almost Always Auto" approach, it's a good anti-pattern, leading to obfuscation, and eliminating the advantages C++ has in large projects over languages like Python.

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you elaborate on how this "eliminates an advantage over Python?" To learn the type of `foo` in C++'s `auto foo = bar();`, you just have to inspect the declaration of `bar()` (or, in any decent IDE, hover your mouse over `foo`). In Python's `foo = bar()`, you have to inspect all `return` statements in `bar()`, possibly recursing to functions called therein.

Comment: @Angew One of the advantages of C++ in large systems is the static type checking.  For that to work, you have to specify the type you expect, otherwise, the compiler has no way of knowing.  When you write `auto foo = bar()`, you get whatever type `bar` decides to return.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *why* you need the size, and what is going to be
in the vector.  Internally, `vector` uses `std::size_t`.  But
that's an unsigned type, inappropriate for numerical values.  If
you just want to display the value, or something, fine, but if
you're using it in any way as a numerical value, the
unsignedness will end up biting you.

Realistically, there are a lot of times the semantics of the
code ensure that the number of values cannot be more than
`INT_MAX`.  For example, when evaluating financial instruments,
the maximum number of elements is less than 20000, so there's no
need to worry about overflowing an `int`.  In other cases,
you'll validate your input first, to ensure that there will
never be overflow.  If you can't do this, the best solution is
probably `ptrdiff_t` (which is the type you get from subtracting
to iterators).  Or if you're using non-standard allocators,
`MyVectorType::difference_type`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already considered this, but what is wrong with `size_t`?
It is what you compiler uses for sizes of builtin containers (i.e. arrays).

Comment: I did. It was actually the first thing that came to mind, and also I assumed that the std containers used this. Then I found that the containers can define their own size type container::size_type.
Why that is would maybe even be a more interesting question.